# How to extend formula for residue to functional calculus of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, operator-theory

Suppose $\{X_t\}$ is a stochastic process with the covariance operator $\Gamma$ and the first $d$ eigen values are $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq \ldots \geq\lambda_d$ with eigen vectors $\{e_1,\ldots,e_d\}$. Let $\Pi_d$ be a orthogonal operator on $\{e_1,\ldots,e_d\}$.

**Goal:** Want to write $\Pi_d$ as a function of $\Gamma$.

If $C_d$ is a closed oriented contour in the complex plane, that is a closed curve endowed with a circulation which contains $\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d\}$, then by formula for residues it can be asserted that $$\int_{C_1}\frac{dz}{z-\lambda_1}=1, and \int_{C_1}\frac{dz}{z-\lambda_i}=0\;\; for\;\; i\neq 1.$$ 
I have seen in a research paper a representation like: $$\Pi_d=\int_{C_d}(zI-\Gamma)^{-1}dz,$$ but could able to derive it from the residues formula. Could any one please help here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest Hille an Phillips "Functional Analysis and Semigroups" and Kato "Perturbation Theory of Linear operators".

Comment: @Urgje. Thanks for attention. Could you please suggest further, where I can get  the proof in the suggested  books (chapter/page no.) .

Comment: Hille and Phillips, Chapter III 3.2 Complex function theory, Kato part about resolvents ans spectra.